# Remove dynamic rendered element from dom in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-manipulation

Currently I've got a react component that looks like this:

```
const GeraCard = (cards, cart = false) => {
    return cards.map((v, i) => {
      return (
        <div key={i} className={styles.card}>
          <div onClick={() => urlRender(v.url)} className={styles.cardContent}>
            <div>
              <span className={styles.cardTitulo}>{v.Nome}</span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span className={styles.cardData}>{v.Data}</span>
              <span className={styles.cardAtivos}>{v.Ativos} ativo(s)</span>
            </div>
            {cart ? <div>R$ {FormatCapital(v.Capital)}</div> : null}
          </div>
          <span className={styles.trash}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon
              icon={faTrash}
              color={"#3c3c3c77"}
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.persist()
                TrashHandler(v.Nome, e)
              }}
            />
          </span>
        </div>
      );
    });
  };
```

Based on the cards array, it renders something like this:

[Rendered Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCkZW.png)

Whenever I click the trash button, I make a request to my backend, edit the list on my database and rerender the component based on the now updated "cards". The problem is that this takes sometime to happen, so i wanted a way to remove it from the dom instantly while my backend does it's job.

somehting like

```
{show ? renderCompoennt : null}
```

I've tried using vanilla javascript to grab the parent from the trash can, which would be the card i want to remove, but the results are unpredictable and it's quite slow as well.

My latest try was this:

```
const GeraCard = (cards, cart = false) => {
    return cards.map((v, i) => {
      const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
      return (
        <div key={i}>
          {show ?
            <div className={styles.card}>
              <div onClick={() => urlRender(v.url)} className={styles.cardContent}>
                <div>
                  <span className={styles.cardTitulo}>{v.Nome}</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <span className={styles.cardData}>{v.Data}</span>
                  <span className={styles.cardAtivos}>{v.Ativos} ativo(s)</span>
                </div>
                {cart ? <div>R$ {FormatCapital(v.Capital)}</div> : null}
              </div>
              <span className={styles.trash}>
                <FontAwesomeIcon
                  icon={faTrash}
                  color={"#3c3c3c77"}
                  onClick={(e) => {
                    setShow(false);
                    e.persist()
                    TrashHandler(v.Nome, e)
                  }}
                />
              </span>
            </div> :
            null
          }
        </div>
      );
    });
  };
```

but react won't let me do this. Even tho its fast, everytime one item gets deleted, react complains that "less hooks were rendered" and crashes the app.

Comment: You can't use `useState` inside a map, I'd suggest extracting the content in map as a component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the first render you have {cards.length} calls to hook "useState" within GeraCard, but after deletion of one card, you will have {cards.length-1} calls to hook "useState". As the React docs state:

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.
> Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function. By
> following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same
> order each time a component renders. That’s what allows React to
> correctly preserve the state of Hooks between multiple useState and
> useEffect calls.

You should extract the content of map callback into separate a component.

```
const GeraCards = (cards, cart = false) => {
    return cards.map((v, i) =>
        <GeraCard card={v} index={i} cart={cart} />
    );
};

const GeraCard = ({ card, index, cart }) => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
    const v = card;
    return (
        <div key={index}>
            {show ?
                <div className={styles.card}>
                    <div onClick={() => urlRender(v.url)} className={styles.cardContent}>
                        <div>
                            <span className={styles.cardTitulo}>{v.Nome}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span className={styles.cardData}>{v.Data}</span>
                            <span className={styles.cardAtivos}>{v.Ativos} ativo(s)</span>
                        </div>
                        {cart ? <div>R$ {FormatCapital(v.Capital)}</div> : null}
                    </div>
                    <span className={styles.trash}>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon
                            icon={faTrash}
                            color={"#3c3c3c77"}
                            onClick={(e) => {
                                setShow(false);
                                e.persist()
                                TrashHandler(v.Nome, e)
                            }}
                        />
                    </span>
                </div> :
                null
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to do some [Optimistic UI](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/11/true-lies-of-optimistic-user-interfaces/), in which you assume that your action will succeed, and reflect the expected/assumed state instantly, before the request to the backend completes.  This would be in lieu of showing some progress/busy indicator, like a spinner, until the action completes with the server.

The first problem and immediate problem in your code-- it violates the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html), which state that hooks may only be used at the top-level (never inside loops, conditionals, etc).

The second problem is that you are leveraging vanilla JS to manipulate the DOM directly; this generally an antipattern in MV* frameworks, and very much so here.  Instead, I would suggest doing managing it in your data model; something like this:

1. Rewrite your `.map` handler to return `null` if the card has a `deleted` property.
2. When the user clicks the trash button, do two things:

   1. Make the request to the backend to delete it
   2. Use a `setState` to add a `deleted: true` property to the clicked card

Now you will get a rerender that will omit the deleted card, and also make the request to the backend, all inside the React data model.  Make sure that you handle complexity for:

1. How to handle the response
2. How to handle an error if the deletion fails at the backend
3. How to manage if a user quickly clicks many cards for deletion before any of the requests can complete.